# Adding jQuery custom image tool tip to jsTree

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jstree

This is basically a follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096803/jquery-jstree-add-a-tooltip)

I am trying to add custom tool tips to a jstree which show thumbnails of the image files if they mouse over them. It should use the node's a href value to mark up thumbnail and stick it in a tool tip. Referencing the above-mentioned post, I have managed to get it to show some arbitrary textual tool tip, but that is obviously not what I want.

If I were simply adding the tool tip to an img tag or an a tag by themselves, I doubt this would be an issue. But, I'm trying to create a custom tool tip for a link that's buried in a bunch of jstree node stuff.

For example:

```
    .on('hover_node.jstree',function(e,data){
            var $node = $("#" + data.node.id);
            var url = $node.find('a').attr('href');

            $("#" + data.node.id).prop('title', url);
        })
```

does a fine job of ... just giving me a text tool tip. But I really don't know where to go from here, I have been beating my head against a wall for hours now, scouring the internet for viable solutions.

```
$(function () {
        $(document).tooltip();

        $('#treeView').jstree({
            'core': {
                'multiple': false,
                'check_callback': true,
                'data': {
                    'url': 'Temp/ajax.html',
                    'data': function (node) {
                        return { 'id': node.id };
                    }
                }
            },
            'checkbox': {
                'three_state': false,
                'whole_node': false
            },
            'plugins': ["checkbox"]
        }).on('hover_node.jstree',function(e,data){
            var $node = $("#" + data.node.id);
            var url = $node.find('a').attr('href');

            $("#" + data.node.id).prop({ 'title': url, 'content': '<img src="' + url + '" alt=""/>' });
        })            
    });
```

All I know is nothing I've tried has worked. I read all of the API docs for the JQuery tool tip plug in, but I'm still pretty  new at this and it's become apparent that I won't be able to brute-force-and-ignorance my way into a solution.

**UPDATE**

So I have revised the code as follows:

```
.on('hover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var $node = $("#" + data.node.id);
            var url = $node.find('a').attr('href');

            if (url != '#') {
                debugger
                //get the mouse position
                var x = $node.position().top + 20;
                var y = $node.position().left;
                $('.tooltip').css({ 'top': y + 'px', 'left': x + 'px' });
                $('.tooltip').find('img').attr('src', url);
                $('.tooltip').fadeIn(300, 'easeOutSine');
            }
        }).on('dehover_node.jstree', function () {
            $('.tooltip').fadeOut(200);
        });
```

and it works..ostensibly. NOW I need to actually figure out how to get the MOUSE POINTER coordinates, not the NODE coordinates. Every image I mouse over down the list, the tool tip shows further and further to the right. I'm figuring out a way to show it AT the mouse pointer.

**LAST UPDATE**

```
    //assigning the right properties to the right
    //variables would work wonders for my cause.
    var x = $node.position().left;
    var y = $node.position().top + 20;
```

Comment: in the jQuery .mouseenter event, the e parameter contains the mouse position data, but it doesn't seem so with the jstree_hover event.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517198/how-to-get-mouse-position-in-jquery-without-mouse-events for getting mouse location.

Comment: that was what I tried originally, but e.pageX and e.pageY both come back undefined for some reason.

Comment: I'm a doofus. It would help if I assigned the right properties to the right variables. I was assigning to top position to x and the left position to y. No wonder it was doing what it was doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you cannot put images or other custom content in the `title` attribute, you will need to create the tooltip yourself. This can be done by simple positioning a `div` below where your hovering with the custom content. The below snippet shows how this can be done.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mouse_x = 0;
  var mouse_y = 0;
  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    mouse_x = event.pageX;
    mouse_y = event.pageY;
  });

  $('#custom_image_content').hide(); // Make sure the custom content does not show by default.

  $('#jsTreeTest').jstree({
      'core': {
        'check_callback': true,

      },
      'plugins': ["checkbox", "dnd", "contextmenu"]
    })
    .on('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
      var $node = $("#" + data.node.id);
      var url = $node.find('a').attr('href');

      //            $("#" + data.node.id).prop('title', url);
      $('#custom_image_content').find('img').attr('src', url);
      $('#custom_image_content')
        .css('position', 'absolute')
        //.css('top', $node.position().top + 20) // Add about 20 to ensure the div is not hovered when we re-position it.
        //.css('left', $node.position().left)
        .css('top', mouse_y)
        .css('left', mouse_x)
        .show();
    })
    .on('dehover_node.jstree', function() {
      $('#custom_image_content').hide(); // Need to hide tooltip after we change hover targets.
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.1/themes/default-dark/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <div id="jsTreeTest">
        <ul>
          <li>Test
            <ul>
              <li>SubDir1
                <ul>
                  <li><a href='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>File1.txt</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>SubDir2
                <ul>
                  <li>SubSubDir1
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>File1.txt</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href='#'>File2.txt</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>File2.txt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>File3.txt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png'>File4.txt</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href='https://s.yimg.com/rz/l/yahoo_en-US_f_p_142x37.png'>File5.txt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="custom_image_content">This is my custom content
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT:** Updated with mouse y and x positions for tooltip placement.

Comment: Hi again, Brant! Heh, this is exactly what I had resolved to do. Thank you! My only question at this point was how to get the x/y position from inside the jstree_hover event, and there it is! You're great, thank you.

Comment: It's done, it looks great now, I'm so extremely happy. Funny, I spent 8 hours breaking my brain over this problem yesterday...wake up this morning and solve it inside half an hour. So that's why my friend is always telling me "if you spend more than x amount of time trying to figure out a problem, walk away. Come back later."