# JSTree - Display additional information about a node?

Tags: javascript, tree, jstree

I want to display additional information for a node when using JSTree for creating a tree diagram.

[image]

If I want to display attributes such as, say `Child name`, `age` etc. along with the node, how would I do it? Is there a plugin that does this?

Comment: Where do you want to display the extra information? In the node itself, or in a seperatly, eg an information box?

Comment: I want to display it along the node, maybe like a list below the node before the children branch, however I think a tool tip would serve this better since the list of items can get big.

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8167174/6060429 You can specify tooltip when you set the script to init the tree. Then within the init script you can construct the content of the tooltip

Comment: Hey thanks, it does have some interesting suggestions, lemme try them out.